# c# winforms sdi application updating multiple progressbars

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, progress-bar, toolstripitem

Happy New Year all,

I am developing a C# Winforms SDI application that relies heavily on background worker threads to carry out long-running database queries. My main dialog box contains a progress label and progress bar; but also a Toolstrip Menu, which contains two ToolStrip Labels and two Toolstrip Progress Bars. I update the progress labels and progress bars via delegates called by event handlers (OnUpdateProgress(object sender UpdateProgressEventArgs e)).

I am seeking your expert opinion on what approach I should use when invoking the UI delegate with regards to trying to achieve a more "generic" and reusable approach.

Thusfar I have considered 2:

(1) When instantiating a worker thread from the main dialog to carry out a background task, pass in a handle to the Label and Progress Bar controls to be updated when the event handler calls back, and
(2) Pass in the name of the Label and Progress Bar to be updated when the event handler is invoked; and use the Form.Find method to retrieve a Control[] of matching controls.

I cannot decide on which of these approaches to use; or indeed if there is a better way of doing this. I believe that method (1) is a little clunky and inelegant; but that method (2) is prone to failure and notwithstanding that the Form.Find method may introduce unreasonable overhead searching for embedded Toolstrip Menu Controls.

I have searched previously asked/answered questions for a solution.

Your advice if much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that worker thread needs to know, what controls should be updated. It just needs to post progress notification to given control (dialog in your case). Function which is invoked, should decide what controls should be updated and how.

Comment: This starts out poorly.  You use a progress bar when you can measure progress.  You can't, you have no idea how long it will take to get a result from the dbase engine.  You don't know until it is done, too late.  You are creating a UI, don't force the user to stare at progress bars.  Make small queries that never take more than a second.

Comment: @Alex. This would mean getting the type of background worker, maybe in a switch statement: switch(sender.GetType()) and acting on different cases, which I wanted to avoid if possible in the UI event handler callback.

Comment: @Hans, I can actually measure progress as the background worker calculates it's workload based on a Count(*) query to determine the number of records in the domain of interest. The records are read using a forward-only data reader. The main loop is controlled using a "while(Reader.Read()) construct. The main loop (1) checks for thread cancellation, (2) fetch 1 record (doing something with match), (3) calls OnUpdateProgress event handler with a computed percentage of work complete. I am just wanted to know if anyone has a more elegant solution.

Comment: Actually, worker thread may be encapsulated in a class, which exposes Progress event. Thread must only know to do the task it is designed for, and notify client, if it is interesting in progress notifications. Even Invoke/BeginInvoke must be called by client - thread may run in non-UI environment or in WPF application. This looks like overkill, but your are talking about program design.

Comment: @Alex. If I encapsulate a background worker thread in a class, which exposes Progress event; I am back to my original problem of identifying which progress bar to update in the UI.